# Mongoose: Send different response for create & update bulkWrite operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I write an API, which is a bulkWrite operation. If it find ID it update or not it will create a new one. that works  properly. But I need to separate responses. When create, I send to response "Create Successfully" If update sends the response "Update Successfully". Here is my code-

```
exports.createOrUpdateQuestion = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { survey_id, fields } = req.body;
  try {
    let cid;
    let addQuestion = [];
    fields.forEach(async (item) => {
      cid = item.cid;
      addQuestion.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { slug: cid },
          update: {
            title: item.label,
            survey_id,
            type: item.field_type,
            slug: item.cid,
          },
          upsert: true,
        },
      });
      await SurveyQuestion.bulkWrite(addQuestion);
    });
    return res.locals.send("Update successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Solved. I just check any questions in this survey_id. if not send to response "Create Successfully" otherwise send "Update Successfully"